# Changing Union to OR

Tags: sql

Question 12. Find the names of students who owned or borrowed a copy of the book ‘978-
0262033848’. Use **UNION**.

```
select s.name
from student s, loan l
where s.email = l.borrower and l.book = '978-0262033848'
union
select s.name
from student s, copy c
where s.email = c.owner and c.book = '978-0262033848';
```

Question 13. Find the names of students who owned or borrowed a copy of the book ‘978-
0262033848’. Use **OR**.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can join these three tables together and then use an `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause to get your desired result set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN loan l
    ON s.email = l.borrower
LEFT JOIN copy c
    ON s.email = c.owner
WHERE l.book = '978-0262033848' OR
      c.book = '978-0262033848';
```

You will also notice that I replaced your implicit joins with explicit left joins, moving the join criteria from the `WHERE` to `ON` clause.  This is best practice, as it makes your query easier to read and maintain.

**Update:**

The query I gave you is the preferred way of doing this.  If you want to stick with the pre ANSI-92 form you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name
FROM student s, loan l, copy c
WHERE s.email = l.borrower OR
      s.email = c.owner AND
      (l.book = '978-0262033848' OR
       c.book = '978-0262033848')
```

Comment: We are told not to use inner joins. Is it still possible? We could only use the from student s, copy c, loan l etc

We can use keywords like  IN, ALL , exists and except

Comment: @RStyle Your original query _is_ using an inner join!

Comment: Hi could you explain this part. 
s.email = l.borrower and s.email = c.owner
Doesnt this mean I have to be both to have owned and borrowed my own book?
What happens if i own a book but I have not borrowed any.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.name
from student s
left join loan as l on s.email = l.borrower
left join copy as c on s.email = c.owner
where l.book = '978-0262033848' or c.book = '978-0262033848'
```